# MediaPlayerElement buffer

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm developing an UWP app that needs to play hls stream and allow user to move back the position of the video up to 15 minutes from live. If I set back the Position property of MediaPlayer to the value close to 1 minute, everything works fine but if the amount is larger the playback just freezes and stream needs to be reoladed to work again. I tried searching the web and setting various properties of  MediaPlayerElement and MediaSource but nothing works. Does anyone have an idea how I can make MediaPlayerElement keep this 15 minutes buffer of stream?

Comment: I tested the scenario 3 of the [AdaptiveStreaming official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AdaptiveStreaming) but after re-seek  it didn't have the issue that freeze. The ninth media is HLS and almost 15 minutes.  Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: The hls i'm streaming is a livestream so its more like video 10 in  scenario 3. By default the seek bar did not work and returned to the 0 value if i tried to move it, just like in the sample. I reimplemented seek bar myself and now if i set MediaSource.DesiredLiveOffset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); stream plays with 5 minute delay from live and im able to seek forward to the live point but if i try to seek back more then a minute playback freezes and for it to work again i need to set the Position parameter to value greather then  (befofre seek back -1).

Comment: Did you change another live stream for testing? Did they have the same result? By the way, could you please provide the code about how you re-implemented seek bar?

Comment: All the seekbar does is changing the value of position of mediaPlayer object. Lets say i play the stream live for 10 minutes and now the position value is set to 10 minutes, then i set the position value to 5 minutes and stream freezes. On android and ios verything works fine and is entirely handled by the Player they use, so stream is fine. Here is the link to feature request for other player https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/87 that explains things a little better than me. I can set DesiredLiveOffset on AdaptiveMediaSource but this requires video reload an is not an ideal solution.